# Using third-party API to constantly(dynamically) refreshing the data List in Flutter framework

Tags: api, flutter, dart, cryptography

I'm trying to make a simple app using Flutter, cryptocurrency price tracker. Using [this API](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=100) to retrieve a data. That how it looks:
[image: app]
The problem is, it only retrieves the latest data and do not updates as the price changes every time. It will change only after restarting an app. I was thinking to add a `floating refresh button` but i seems an old school. **SO my aim is to let it update the price by itself,in real time(LIVE) without USER doing something, every time there is a change in price.** My question is, what technology is behind this ? How could I implement this ? What should I Google in order to find the required knowledge ? Who could give me the right direction to think and learn. I don't really know the special terminology for this concepts, tried my best to explain the question. Thnx!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878832/flutter-refresh-json-every-minute-automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How could I implement this ?

Following are the steps that you need to follow.

1. Create a stateful  widget with a [Periodic Timer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html) object. setup the timer value, say 10 seconds.
2. Now you will get a callback for every 10 seconds. So, from that callback method, simply call the API end point to fetch the latest data.
3. Use [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) method to show the latest data on the UI.

Thats all, now your app will refresh the data by its own for every 10 seconds without any user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use web sockets.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

This will let you push updates to the client without polling in real time.